# Integration SQL Server and Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I wonder if it is possible to make the Active Directory authentication point to a base in SQL Server, where I have the usernames and passwords.

Comment: already answered this below, is basically for all systems and to use the same active directory password.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759073(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the applications were not able to authenticate to the active directory, THEY MUST authenticate this database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variety of [tools](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ed20b349-9758-4c70-adc0-19c5acfcae45) to import the users and passwords into Active Directory; storing the users and passwords in SQL permanently is just a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the intention is that all my systems authenticate to the sql server, however I would like the system passwords were the same as the active directory, the best solution I found was to get the active directory use this base usernames and passwords for authentication.